# VIM does not refresh properly

Tags: vim

I have a VM box with LAMP installed

I use the shell (with ubuntu 12) to connect to the VM box and real server (dell poweredge), every time I press page up or page down, the screen does not get refreshed on both VMs and Physical servers.

Both VM and real server have this config:

- 2 gigs ram
- 1,8G processor
- 250g hdd
- 2 x gigabit LAN port #1 used, port #2 not used
- Both are plugged to a 1u switch
- all servers has Ubuntu server 12.04

Client's computer:

3.2 G I5, 16g ram, SSD, Nvidia gtx550ti with Ubuntu 12.04

I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078538/refresh-vim-buffer

works but it's a pain to do every time i press up arrow, page up etc...

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
set nowrap
set showmatch
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
"set expandtab
set ruler
set foldcolumn=2
set nowrap
nmap <F8> :set wrap! wrap?<CR>
"nmap <F6> :e /tmp/a<CR>
"nmap <F7> :w! /tmp/a\| wq!<CR>

" change // style comment to phpDoc comment
map <C-P> :!php -l %<CR>

set hlsearch
"set incsearch
set background=dark
"set textwidth=1000
"set number
"set backspace=indent,eol,start
set noshowmatch

syntax on
let g:loaded_matchparen=1 
:set nocp
```

is there a solution to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to put these in your .vimrc:

```
  autocmd GuiEnter * set background&

  set ttimeoutlen=100
  set ttyfast
  set lazyredraw

  :au CursorMoved
  autocmd BufReadPost quickfix map <buffer> <leader>qq :cclose<cr>|map <buffer> <c-p> <up>|map <buffer> <c-n> <down>
  set synmaxcol=120
  set nocursorline
  set re=1
  :redraw
```

Another solution can be:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030290/syntax-highlighting-causes-terrible-lag-in-vim

I had the same issue and these worked for me on my 15k drive. On my SSD drive these never worked, do you have a SSD drive by any chance?

My error was similar, I had a SSD drive to another SSD drive using a bad network switch and poor network cables. I changed everything and since then I don't have any issues.